# Mason graph for linear system

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory

I need to solve simple system of linear equations by Mason graph method. I can solve this system any method of linear algebra (inverse matrix method, Gaussian elimination, Cramer's rule). For example, I take system: $$\begin{cases} 3x+4y=3\\4x+y=17 \end{cases}$$. The solution is $(5;-3)$. Please help me to build Mason graph for this equation and explain what steps should I do for solution.
Should I modify system this way:  $$\begin{cases} x=4x+4y-3\\y=4x+2y-17 \end{cases}$$
[image]